# Common Sources of this bug include user marshaling error for COM-interop or Pinvoke, which may corrupt the stack

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, serial-port

I am trying to make a GUI to interact with my servo driver. The program runs fine and does not have any compile error but after running around 10 to 15 sec I get the error about which i have no idea about.

I have read several post about the using serial port call in C# and avoiding some bugs in it. Having read those post i followed their suggestion on how to use but i still have problem.

I have uploaded my Program(GUI) in github and  [this is the link for github](https://github.com/mechbaral/ParkerGUI).

Below is the snapshot of my code in error.

[image: My code Snapshot]

While reading online to find reason for the error, i saw some saying that the for them the error occurs at random place of their code but unlike them the error is always in ReadPort function which is started handled in another thread rather than main.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what was casing the problem but I made some changes in ReadPort() method in my SerialPortManager class as shown below and the GUI is working good so far.

```js
public void ReadPort()
{
  string ReceivedMessage = "No Message";
  if (_serialPort == null)
   {
     return;
   }
  while (_keepReading)
   {
        List<byte> receiveBuffer = new List<byte>();
        int bytesToRead = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
        _serialPort.Read(tempBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
        receiveBuffer.AddRange(tempBuffer);

        ReceivedMessage = _serialPort.Encoding.GetString(receiveBuffer.ToArray());
        
        if (OnDataReceived != null)
            OnDataReceived(this, ReceivedMessage);
 }
}
```

Rest of the code is same as uploaded in the github